# Alfresco: Failed to create directory

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have created a simple example to create document in alfresco using apache chemistry. I was working fine and able to create document. But when I restart my machine and alfresco server then now same program giving me error-

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: 06220002 Failed to create directory for file storage: /home/alfresco/alfresco-community/alf_data/contentstore/2016/7/22/16/57
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:523)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:717)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:122)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:1165)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:77)
>       at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:460)
>       at com.bizruntime.alfresco.cmis.upload.CreateDocument.createDocumentInAlfrescoRepository(CreateDocument.java:81)
>       at com.bizruntime.alfresco.cmis.upload.CreateDocumentTest.testCreateDocInAlfrescoRepository(CreateDocumentTest.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

please someone help.

Comment: What's the full exception from your `alfresco.log` file? There should be a "caused by" second exception that explains the issue

Comment: thanx for reply, when I am starting catalina.sh from terminal, this exception is showing **java.io.FileNotFoundException: alfresco.log (Permission denied)**

Comment: what do you mean with directory, a `Folder` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an issue with file permissions on your host! To verify the issue you will need to upload/create a document in alfresco using the share interface, if you were not successful, this means my doubts are right: The system user running your tomcat instance does not have the right to write to alf_data directory.

**Possible reasons :** System mis-configuration, You are running alfresco service with a different user ....

**Candidate solution :**

1. Detect which user should be running alfresco (probably the owner of `/home/alfresco`) You can find it out by running this :

   ```
   root@alfhost$>ls -la /home/alfresco
   ```
2. Assuming that the username is `alfresco`, run this script with root account on your host :

   ```
   root@alfhost$>chown alfresco /home/alfresco -R
   ```
3. Restart your service using that same account

Comment: thnx for reply, when I again restart my system and executed same program then it's running fine. I didn't understand why?

Comment: You were running alfresco with the wrong user the first time

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked fine for me

```
public static void createNewFolderIn(String serverUrl, String username, String password, String path, String folderName) {
    Folder root = getFolderByPath(serverUrl, username, password, path);
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_FOLDER.value());

    properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, folderName);
    List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Ace> removeAces = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Policy> policies = new LinkedList<>();
    Folder newFolder = root.createFolder(properties, policies, addAces, removeAces, getSession(serverUrl, username, password).getDefaultContext());

}
```